# Simple move uiimageview code not animating

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the following routine to simply animate an image across the screen.

```
-(void)animateGrasland {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(100,100,1024,768);
                             self.grasland.frame = newFrame;

                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }
         ];
}
```

I want to start the animation immediately after I load the View. And to last for 5 seconds. So I have been experimenting with several options to calls of the function.

Option I - This option immediately shows the image at the new position, no animation!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self animateGrasland];
}
```

Option II - This option animates the image to the new position. Bingo.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(animateGrasland) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I have bene playing with the delay in the Time a little and for 0.001 sec the animation will start. If the duration is 0.0001 sec the image is displayed immediately at the new position, so without animation. I expect that the duration of the parsing of the viewDidLoad (and other background routines causes this).

So because the initial position (0,0), which is set in the storyboard, is updated during the viewDidLoad, the Animation is not triggered. And the animation moves immediately to its finished state.

Comment: you want the animation to last for 5 secs or do you want to execute it after 5 secs?

Comment: try moving the code `CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
    self.grasland.frame = newFrame;` to some place else, such as to the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I've just tried your code on a normal UIView and it works as expected - the animation lasts 5 seconds. Where about in the code do you run this animation? Is self.grasland a UIView object?

Comment: @Divya, duration of the animation 5 sec. No delay (see the 0.0 n the question)

Comment: When do you execute that animation code?

Comment: @Vincent hey, I tried your code.Its working as expected. Are you sure animations are enabled.Try setting `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];` before animating.Also, when are you calling the animation code??

Comment: Are you sure you want to animate it when the view is "loaded", or when the view "appears"? Try placing this in `viewDidAppear:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `animateGrasland` in `viewDidAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]
    [self animateGrasland];
}

// Remove your implementation of the viewDidLoad method or at least the call to animateGrasland
```

`viewDidLoad` is called after the view is loaded into the memory, while `viewDidAppear:` is called after the view is added to the view hierarchy. In your case, this means right after the view is visible. Since you want your animation to start as soon as the view is visible, you should start it in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: That one is even better, as using a timer. Thanks!